# how to push the array values in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

*My Expected Output*

```
var Album = {
    album_desc: AlbumTitle,
    id: 1,
    album_title: 'ss',
    AlbumDescription: 'sdsd',    
    ImageName: 'image.jpg',    
    album_pics: below array
};
```

I need to push the array dynamically like below,Above is my array how can i use this dynamically while uploading images ? how can i push the array in array ? Any suggestions ?

```
"album_pics": [{
    "media_type": "image",
    "last_modified_date": "2015-01-16T00:40:39.071Z",
    "thumnail_pic_loc": "3fe2a54346b3d54e-pinaki2.jpg",
    "large_pic_loc": "3fe2a54346b3d54e-pinaki2.jpg",
    "filter_type": "image/jpeg",
    "pic_id": "d5bc"
}
```

My expected output:

```
{
    "album_desc": "Album 1",
    "id": "399234688",
    "album_title": "Album 1",
    "album_pics": [{
        "media_type": "image",
        "last_modified_date": "2015-01-16T00:40:39.071Z",
        "thumnail_pic_loc": "3fe2a54346b3d54e-pinaki2.jpg",
        "large_pic_loc": "3fe2a54346b3d54e-pinaki2.jpg",
        "filter_type": "image/jpeg",
        "pic_id": "d5bc"
    }, {
        "media_type": "image",
        "last_modified_date": "2015-01-16T00:40:39.071Z",
        "thumnail_pic_loc": "3fe2a54346b3d54e-pinaki3.jpg",
        "large_pic_loc": "3fe2a54346b3d54e-pinaki3.jpg",
        "filter_type": "image/jpeg",
        "pic_id": "d5bd"
    }],            
}
```

Comment: Where is your code that's generating this output?

Comment: its a static i was created @Mc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Like this

```js
 var Album = {
     album_desc: AlbumTitle,
     id: 1,
     album_title: 'ss',
     AlbumDescription: 'sdsd',
     ImageName: 'image.jpg',
     album_pics: [{
         "media_type": "image",
         "last_modified_date": "2015-01-16T00:40:39.071Z",
         "thumnail_pic_loc": "3fe2a54346b3d54e-pinaki2.jpg",
         "large_pic_loc": "3fe2a54346b3d54e-pinaki2.jpg",
         "filter_type": "image/jpeg",
         "pic_id": "d5bc"
     }]
 };
 var newPics = {
     "media_type": "image",
     "last_modified_date": "2015-01-16T00:40:39.071Z",
     "thumnail_pic_loc": "3fe2a54346b3d54e-pinaki3.jpg",
     "large_pic_loc": "3fe2a54346b3d54e-pinaki3.jpg",
     "filter_type": "image/jpeg",
     "pic_id": "d5bd"
 };
 Album.album_pics.push(newPics);
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this way. It work for me.

```js
var album = {
    "album_desc": "Album 1",
    "id": "399234688",
    "album_title": "Album 1",
    "album_pics": [{
        "media_type": "image",
        "last_modified_date": "2015-01-16T00:40:39.071Z",
        "thumnail_pic_loc": "3fe2a54346b3d54e-pinaki2.jpg",
        "large_pic_loc": "3fe2a54346b3d54e-pinaki2.jpg",
        "filter_type": "image/jpeg",
        "pic_id": "d5bc"
    }, ],            
}

var pic = {
        "media_type": "image",
        "last_modified_date": "2015-01-16T00:40:39.071Z",
        "thumnail_pic_loc": "3fe2a54346b3d54e-pinaki3.jpg",
        "large_pic_loc": "3fe2a54346b3d54e-pinaki3.jpg",
        "filter_type": "image/jpeg",
        "pic_id": "d5bd"
    };

album.album_pics.push(pic);

console.log(album);
```